# Android: how to interrupt during a talkback (accessibility) when the "focus" is on a specific view?

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback, accessibilityservice

So, I have an Android application written in Java.  I want to be able to use talkback in the accessibility option for those that are visually impaired.  As the user swipes through the activity, the talkback "focuses" on various components and I want to be able to know this:

1) How to know if it's "focused" on a certain component (ex, textview)?

2) When it's "focused" on that certain component, how to interrupt it to play my own audio file then go back and let talkback take over again?

Thank you in advance!

---- edit

Just to be a little bit more clear, in case you're not familiar with talkback...

Once the user enables talkback, it reads out everything on the phone screen.  If the user wants to select an application, the user will keep swiping right,left,up, or down until that application name is highlighted/focused and announced by the talkback.  So, I want to know when a specific textview is highlighted.

Comment: Use a `View.OnFocusChangeListener` on a view, such as a TextView, to determine when it has focus.

Comment: I tried it on a textview, but it doesn't seem to work.  I think I have to do something with AccessibilityEvent stuff, perhaps... @EdGeorge

Comment: TalkBack focus is separate from regular focus.  This is why this approach doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer A:

Find the views View.AccessibilityDelegate.

Then override the following method:

```
@Override
public boolean onRequestSendAccessibilityEvent(View child, AccessibilityEvent event) {
    if(event.getEventType() == TYPE_VIEW_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUSED) {
        /*do your stuff here*/
    } else {
        return super.onRequestSendAccessibilityEvent(child, event);
    }
}
```

You want to look for events of the type `TYPE_VIEW_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUSED`.

Answer B: Under WCag 2.0 Guideline 3.2, it is generally considered poor accessibility to have things automatically happen on focus.  Instead of figuring out how to make the accessibility framework do something that is generally considered inaccessible, just don't do it instead :).

Comment: Yeah, I agree with your answer B.  I just made another field/button to do what I wanted it to do! Thanks!